# ffmpeg making flashing / blinking text

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to add blinking / flashing text to a short movie file.

The code attached works for blinking text every 10th frame BUT the text only comes up for a single frame, so it's not very readable. I'd like it to hold for, say, 4 frames. I wonder if theres some kinda fancy combo using *between* as well as *enable*?

I'm semi new to this so my brain stopped when trying to come up with a solution.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf "drawtext=text='TEXTY':enable= (not (mod(n\,10)) )" output.gif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do 4 frames on, 6 frames off, you need say ON when the mod value is <4:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
ON  ON  ON  ON  OFF OFF OFF OFF OFF OFF
```

So your enable expression should read:

```
enable= lt(mod(n\,10)\,4)
```

Comment: You are a damn legend, thank you, and for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @kesh for a most excellent solution which combines *less than* and *mod*. For anyone that wants to understand this and isn't mathematically inclined (like me!), here's my understanding. Please shout if you think I'm mistaken in anything.

Kesh's solution:

```
enable= lt(mod(n\,10)\,4)
```

**enable** tells ffmpeg when to display the text

**lt** returns True if the first argument is *less than* the second.

**mod** returns the remainder when you divide the frame number (by 10 in this case)

SO whenever **lt** returns True the text gets drawn on screen.

```
frame 1:  1 mod 10= 1 (which is less than 4) so lt says TRUE
frame 2:  2 mod 10= 2 (which is less than 4) so lt says TRUE
frame 3:  3 mod 10= 3 (which is less than 4) so lt says TRUE
frame 4:  4 mod 10= 4 (which is not less than 4) so lt says FALSE
frame 5:  5 mod 10= 5 (which is not less than 4) so lt says FALSE
.
.
frame 9:  9 mod 10= 9 (which is less than 4) so lt says FALSE
frame 10:  10 mod 10= 0 (which is less than 4) so lt says TRUE
frame 11:  11 mod 10= 1 (which is less than 4) so lt says TRUE
```